# SQL - Mostrar fecha en formato "Lun dd-mm-yyyy"

Tags: date, sql-server-2008, formato

He buscado en Stack Overflow pero no lo encuentro.

En SQL Sever 2008 tengo una tabla llamada "tbltemp" con un campo llamado "día", este campo es tipo DateTime.

Cuando consulto fechas directas sobre este campo, muestra lo siguiente:
Select dia from tbltep

```
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-03-21 00:00:00.000
2017-03-22 00:00:00.000
2017-03-23 00:00:00.000
```

Me gustaría transformar la consulta para que lo arroje de la siguiente forma:

```
Lun 20-03-2017
Mar 21-03-2017
Mie 22-03-2017
Jue 23-03-2017
```

etc.

*(La consulta que poseo es mucho mas grande que eso pero efectivamente requiero transformar los datos datetime)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes usar una combinación de `DATENAME` y `CONVERT` (si tuvieras SQL Server 2012 en adelante, esto sería más sencillo):

```
SET Language 'Spanish';


SELECT  Dia,
        LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Dia),3) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dia,105) Dia_Formateado
FROM dbo.tbltemp;
```

[**Acá hay un link**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=45b256db10d35938862f7ec205add59a) con un demo de este código.

Y los resultados son:

```
╔═════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║         Dia         ║ Dia_Formateado ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 20/03/2017 00:00:00 ║ Lun 20-03-2017 ║
║ 21/03/2017 00:00:00 ║ Mar 21-03-2017 ║
║ 22/03/2017 00:00:00 ║ Mié 22-03-2017 ║
║ 23/03/2017 00:00:00 ║ Jue 23-03-2017 ║
╚═════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Y una forma de hacer esto en SQL Server 2012 en adelante es usando `FORMAT`:

```
SET Language 'Spanish';

SELECT Dia,
       FORMAT(Dia, 'ddd dd-MM-yyyy') Dia_Formateado
FROM dbo.tbltemp;
```

[**Acá va un link**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6f6536fb11d433fa5d449b6db54d5b94) con un demo con ambas versiones.

Comment: No está demás que incluyas con las funciones de `SQL Server 2012` :)

Comment: @Davlio Listo, gracias por el comentario

Comment: Me ha servido mucho tu ejemplo y funciona a la perfección, ahora solo debo averiguar el porque me falla cuando lo paso al español, ya que en ingles funciona perfecto.

Se cambió la configuración de idioma a Español.
`Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.`

Comment: @Ejp Cuál es el tipo de datos de la columna `día` en tu tabla?, el error que obtienes es porque seguramente es un string. Si es así, necesito saber qué datos tienes guardados ahí para poder ayudarte

Comment: esta como: `día (PK, datetime, not null)` , estas son bases creadas por el 1993 aprox. no se si tenga que ver, de hecho el programa que las gestiona es visual fox pro

Comment: @Ejp Que extraño, puedes postear el código exacto que estás usando?

Comment: no permite mostrar la query la página, me dice que tengo 14xx caracteres demás jaja

Comment: @Ejp ocupa el link [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c95f91fb612e81a1822267d22167d4e5) y modifica ahí la consulta. Quizás de esa forma puedes darme el link modificado y ver tu consulta. Si no, puedes usar pastebin

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=41e44596a18bb1655498d54e2d45419d

Comment: @Ejp El problema es con la forma que estás usando tus variables `@fechaInicio` y `@fechafin`. Los declaras como `varchar(10)` y luego los usas directamente para comparar con una columna que es `datetime`. O usas `CONVERT` con el formato correspondiente de fecha, o usas un formato universal (que es `varchar(8)` en forma `YYYYMMDD`). [Acá está el código modificado](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d805ccce4d91d19b25d763a98558d282)

Comment: Jajaja toda la razón, funcionó perfecto!! muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Ejp ningún problema.